# hibernate create user to friend relationship

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping

I am using hibernate and trying to represent a user to friend relationship.  My first thoughts are to create a user object with a Set of friend objects.

I would like a user table with all users and info like:

*User table: first name, last name, etc.*

And then a User_Friend table to manage the relationships.  Something like:

*User_Friend table: id,userId,friendId(userId) *

A user would have many friendIds.

I have created a table and mapping for a user object:

```
<id name="id" type="int">
        <column name="userId" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <set name="friends" table="User_Friend???" 
                inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="userId" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many entity-name="Friend">
                <column name="friendId" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>
        <property name="firstName" type="string"></property>
        <property name="lastName" type="string"></property>
        <property name="email" type="string"></property>
```

What will the mapping for my friend object look like if I want to keep the friend info (like first name, last name, etc.) in the user table and the relationship in a table like User_Friend?

Should I handle friends as essentially users?  If so would I change the User_Friend table above to the User table?

**Edited:**
I have found this [link to hibernate ref](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/associations.html#assoc-bidirectional-join-12m) which explains a bidirectional one to many / many to one with join table.
Will this allow me to create a user to friend relationship without duplicating the user table (for friend)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is "Many-to-many self referencing in Hibernate"

In below example an Employee can have many colleagues:

[image: Self reference many to many]

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

    //id, firstname, lastname 

   @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="EMPLOYEE_COLLEAGUE",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="COLLEAGUE_ID")})
    private Set<Employee> colleagues = new HashSet<Employee>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="colleagues")
    private Set<Employee> teammates = new HashSet<Employee>();     

    // Getter and Setter methods
}
```

See tutorial: [Many to many hibernate self referencing](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-self-join-annotation-mapping-many-to-many-example/)

Answer (score -1):

Try two tables:

```
Users -- with your user information
user_friends -- with two user_ids representing a friendship.
```

Your business logic can indicate whether the relationship is bidirectional or one way.